# Automation in React Native

Tags: ios, react-native, automation

I have requirements for some automation, tests and otherwise, to run on a React-Native App i'm developing.

Are there any tools like phantomJS or something like that, that would run on the simulator for React Native Apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [wix Detox](https://github.com/wix/Detox), we're using it, it allows you to run end-to-end UI tests, where your application is run in the simulator.

Comment: I will accept your anwer as the answer in a couple of days, just leaving the question open to see if there are more suggestions.